# Plotting points in a specific area of a picture

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot points on a picture:

I have the following df

```
x <- c(1,2)
y <- c(10,12)
df <- data.frame(x,y
```

The following picture - [tennis court](https://www.google.nl/search?q=tennis+court&biw=1366&bih=650&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVm_22m7PLAhWEJZoKHQi5C88Q_AUIBigB#imgrc=JEXXgYu0OgVDdM%3A)

[image]

```
 img <- readJPEG("tennis_court.jpg")
```

And the following code to plot the picture

```
 ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
 annotation_custom(rasterGrob(img, width=unit(1,"npc"), height=unit(1,"npc")), 
                   -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf) +
 stat_bin2d() +
 scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
 scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

This works but I would like to plot the point on a specific area. So let's say I want to plot it in the left service area of the right side of the pitch.

Any thought how I can classify a specific part of the picture so that the points are plotted in that area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
library(jpeg)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(scales)

download.file("https://i.stack.imgur.com/BozHb.jpg", tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".jpg"), mode="wb")
img <- readJPEG(tf)
x <- c(1,2)
y <- c(10,12)
df <- data.frame(x, y)

ggplot(transform(df, x=rescale(x, c(0.51, 0.75)), y=rescale(y, c(.2, .5))), 
      aes(x,y)) + 
annotation_custom(rasterGrob(img, width=unit(1,"npc"), height=unit(1,"npc")), -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf) +
stat_bin2d() +
scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits = c(0, 1)) +
scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits = c(0, 1))
```

Comment: thanks! Works like a charm! And any thought how i can change my plotting points (colour and size)?

Comment: You're welcome. Try `+ geom_point(size=10, shape=15, color="red")` to plot big red squared for example.